# Extracting lines to new files

Tags: text-processing, awk, pattern-matching

Say I have a large CSV file with a header and several columns. For the purpose of this question I will consider a small file with just two columns. We can call it `use_rep`.

```
user_id,rep
885,500K+
22565,200K+
7453,200K+
86440,100K+
116858,100K+
22222,100K+
38906,100K+
10762,<100K
70524,<100K
```

I'd like to send each row to a file corresponding to the value on the second column. For example, I'd like there to be a file whose name is `200K+` and whose content is

```
user_id,rep
22565,200K+
7453,200K+
```

The contents of `use_rep` should not be assumed to be ordered in anyway. The pattern to be used would ideally accept regular expressions.

No sed or perl is preferred.

Comment: I think `AWK` can do this easily, but I don't really know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the header (which you can tack on later):

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 {print > $2}' use_rep
```

which will print each line to a file named by the second column:

```
~ head *[0-9]*
==> 100K+ <==
86440,100K+
116858,100K+
22222,100K+
38906,100K+

==> 200K+ <==
22565,200K+
7453,200K+

==> 500K+ <==
885,500K+

==> <100K <==
10762,<100K
```

To put the header, maybe something like:

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 {header = $0; next} # save header, skip this line
  !a[$2]++ { print header > $2 } # print if second field hasnt been seen before 
  { print > $2 }' use_rep
```

Result:

```
~ head *[0-9]*
==> 100K+ <==
user_id,rep
86440,100K+
116858,100K+
22222,100K+
38906,100K+

==> 200K+ <==
user_id,rep
22565,200K+
7453,200K+

==> 500K+ <==
user_id,rep
885,500K+

==> <100K <==
user_id,rep
10762,<100K
70524,<100K
```

Comment: I'm having some issues with this due to commas inside text identifiers (`"` `"`). Is there an easy fix?

Comment: Not with awk. You should use a tool with support for quoted csv, like csvkit or Python or Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

command

```
for i in `awk -F "," '{print $2}' l.txt | sort | uniq`; do sed -n '/'$i'$/p' l.txt > $i.txt ; done
```